# What types of sockets are available in VxWorks?

Tags: sockets, vxworks

Vxworks supports standard IP v4 and IP v6 sockets, but sockets are also used for other purposes.
What other types of sockets are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket types you can use depend on the communication domain you create your socket in.
The listed socket types are:

```
SOCK_DGRAM      unreliable  not sequenced  possibly duplicated  message
SOCK_STREAM     reliable      sequenced       non-duplicated    stream
SOCK_SEQPACKET  reliable      sequenced       non-duplicated    message
SOCK_RDM        reliable    not sequenced  possibly duplicated  message

SOCK_RAW        protocol/interface dependent, access to internal protocol info
```

VxWorks also defines the following communication domains:

```
AF_INET     IPv4
AF_INT6     IPv6
AF_ROUTE    routing
AF_LOCAL    local Inter-process Communications
AF_TIPC     Transparent Inter-Process Communications
AF_MOBILITY Mobile IPv6
```

Here is the list of the various sockets supported for the various domains:

```
AF_INET     SOCK_DGRAM, SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_RAW
AF_INT6     SOCK_DGRAM, SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_RAW
AF_ROUTE    SOCK_RAW
AF_LOCAL    SOCK_SEQPACKET
AF_TIPC     SOCK_SEQPACKET, SOCK_RDM, SOCK_DGRAM, SOCK_STREAM
AF_MOBILITY don't know
```